# Import excel data into TwinCat3

Tags: plc, twincat

I want to enter large amount of data in `twincat3` as an array. 
I have 6000*2 matrix(one column as time and other one is value corresponding of function).

I read [this](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/english.php?content=../content/1033/tf6420_tc3_database_server/27021598471404939.html&id=) link of `Beckhoff` but it was a bit hazy for me. I'm looking for a simple example of how to load and use excel data in `twincat3`.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The link you included references the TF6429 Connectivity module. Here's [a link](https://download.beckhoff.com/download/document/automation/twincat3/TF6420_TC3_Database_Server_EN.pdf) to the documentation for that module. The specifics are in the documentation. As an FYI - the minimum steps you'll need to take are:

1. Download that module
2. Add it as a new TwinCat Connectivity project to your solution.
3. Add your excel sheet as a database connection.
4. Refer to chapter 6 of the documentation for PLC API instructions.

Best of luck!